# Can anyone prove this identity without passing through the complexified tangent space?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $\rho: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function, $\Omega = \{ z : \rho(z) <0 \}$, and suppose $|\nabla \rho| = 1$ on $b\Omega$.

It is true that

$$\int_{b\Omega}  f(z) d\bar{z}  = -2i \int_{b\Omega} f(z) \frac{\partial \rho}{ \partial z} dS$$

I can prove this by thinking of $d\bar{z}$ as acting on the complexified tangent bundle to $\mathbb{C}$ as follows:

$\begin{align}
\int_{b\Omega}  f(z) d\bar{z} &= \int_{b\Omega}  f(z) dz \wedge d\bar{z}( \frac{\partial }{\partial z}, \cdot)\\
&= \int_{b\Omega} f(z)dz \wedge d\bar{z} (d \rho(\frac{\partial }{\partial z}) \nabla \rho, \cdot) \text{ projecting $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ in the direction of $\nabla \rho$ does not change $\\$the value of the differential form, since $\cdot$ is tangent to $b\Omega$}\\
&=\int_{b\Omega}f(z) \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z} dz \wedge d\bar{z}(\nabla \rho, \cdot)\\
&=-2i\int_{b\Omega} f(z) \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z} dV(\nabla \rho, \cdot)\\
&=-2i\int_{b\Omega} f(z) \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z} dS \text{ Since $dS$ is defined to be $dV \lrcorner \nabla \rho$}
\end{align}$

I also have a geometric "proof" of this fact:

$f(z)d\bar{z} = f(z)\frac{d\bar{z}}{|d\bar{z}|} |d\bar{z}|$.

$|d\bar{z}| = dS$, and geometrically $\frac{d\bar{z}}{|d\bar{z}|}$ should be the conjugate of the normalized tangent vector to the boundary.  But $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y}$  is the unit normal to the boundary, so $i(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y})$ is the unit tangent.  Thus we should have $\frac{d\bar{z}}{|d\bar{z}|} = \overline{i(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y})} = -2i(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} -  \frac{i}{2}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y}) = -2i \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z}$.

The RHS and LHS of the identity we are discussing do not need any talk of the complexified tangent bundle to make  sense.  Can anyone show me a proof which does not pass through the complexified bundle?  This is probably elementary, but I cannot see one now.

My actually interest is in the generalization of this formula to several variables, but I think everything interesting already occurs here.

Comment: By $b\Omega$ do you mean what is often denoted $\partial \Omega$, the boundary of $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes.  I use "b" for "boundary".

Comment: OK, got it!  Thanks!  Nice question, +1!